# Getting Error while deploying smart contract on rinkeby testnet

Tags: solidity, truffle, rinkeby

I am using truffle and trying to deploy my smart contract on rinkeby testnetwork

My network conf.

```
rinkeby: {
  privider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/--key--`),
  network_id: 4,
  gas: 4500000,
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
}
```

But whenever I am hitting this command `truffle migrate --network rinkeby` I am getting an error

```
Something went wrong while attempting to connect to the network. Check your network configuration.
Could not connect to your Ethereum client.
Please check that your Ethereum client:
- is running
- is accepting RPC connections (i.e., "--rpc" option is used in geth)
- is accessible over the network
- is properly configured in your Truffle configuration file (truffle-config.js)
```

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

In your network config file you write privider instead of provider.

Try this:

```
rinkeby: {
  provider: () => new HDWalletProvider(mnemonic, `https://rinkeby.infura.io/v3/--key--`),
  network_id: 4,
  gas: 4500000,
  gasPrice: 10000000000,
}
```